# React Native this.setState() only re-renders after interacting with the component again

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate, rerender

Normally when using this.setState(), the component re-renders after updating state via setState(). Unfortunately, I have this problem where the state updates but the component doesn't re-render until interacting with the component again (i.e. clicking the component again).
Here's my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: new Date(),
      time: 0,
      displayTime: null,
      show: false,
    };
    this.showTimePicker = this.showTimePicker.bind(this);
  }

  showTimePicker() {
    console.log(this.state.show);
    this.setState({show: true}, () => console.log(this.state.show));
    //console.log to verify state changes
  }


render() {
 return(
  <View>
  //code that determines if the datetimepicker modal shows up
  {this.state.show && (
     <DateTimePicker
        value={this.state.value}
        mode="time"
        display="spinner"
        onChange={(date, value) => {
           console.log(value, 'value');
           this.setTime(value);
           setShow(this.state.show);
        }}
      />
   )}
   
   //when button is pressed this.state.show changes to true
   <Button title="Change Time" onPress={this.showTimePicker}></Button>
   </View>
);}
```

So what I want is for the DateTimePicker modal to show up every time the button is pressed. What happens currently though is when I press the button nothing registers (state still changes) until I click the screen again (then the modal shows up). How can I get it so that the button makes the modal pops up instantly?

Comment: Could you give this a try?:
{this.state.show ? (
     <DateTimePicker
        value={this.state.value}
        mode="time"
        display="spinner"
        onChange={(date, value) => {
           console.log(value, 'value');
           this.setTime(value);
           setShow(this.state.show);
        }}
      />
   ) : null }

Comment: I just tried it, the problem still persists though.

Comment: @JerryZhou can you explain what are you trying to achieve by adding `this.setTime(value); setShow(this.state.show);` in your `onChange` prop within the DateTimePicker? I don't see your complete code but with the info you shared this does not seem correct to me.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault that I didn't show the setTime() function. I didn't think the code was relevant to the question. Essentially, setTime() changes a text component on the screen to show the updated time from the modal. The setShow() function is a prop that hides the modal from popping up repeatedly after getting a response from the user. 
As it turns out, the problem was with using the debugging mode for some reason, so turning it off makes the app work like usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue while I was using the app in `debug mode`, So can just disable the debug mode and it should work properly.

Here is the similar question : [UI doesn't update until tap on the screen when setState is called inside a realm listener callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044770/ui-doesnt-update-until-tap-on-the-screen-when-setstate-is-called-inside-a-realm)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question! Turns out that was all I needed was this fix.